# How to obfuscate or Encrypt Client-Server comms

Tags: android, ios, swift, encryption, obfuscation

I have a mobile app (iOS/Android) which sends some sensitive data to an API (users don't need to authenticate to use it). Though the connection is SSL encrypted, I'd like to avoid people looking into the data through tools like Charles.

How would I go about it? Should I encrypt the data? Obfuscate?

Performance is important, so using AES-256 would be an overkill for this

Thanks

Comment: Yes, obfuscate it, and perhaps rethink your entire design. Don't put sensitive data in client-side apps. You can use certificate pinning to make using tools like Charles more painful, but it would not take great skill to overcome this using for example something like Frida. Obfuscation only works minimally motivated attackers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider implementing Certificate Pinning and domain whitelisting. Those combined, allow you to establish secure connections with only the domains you trust (domain whitelisting) and trust only the certificates that your apps(clients) know in advance, preventing MiTM attacks (without it, the normal SSL can be workaround with simple client proxies such as Charles proxy or similar)

ref to pinning: https://labs.nettitude.com/tutorials/tls-certificate-pinning-101/

Additionally, you may consider implementing protocols such as OAuth 1.a or ver 2, with token exchange. This one requires some extra work server side but provides an extra strong layer of security within the normal SSL channel

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Luca - but using pinning is just a way to Public Key encrypt the data (I could use symmetrical encryption as well, which should be faster), which might be just an overkill for this and would require much more processing time. Or am I missing something

Comment: certificate pinning is not encrypting anything, it’s meant to be a whitelisting of the ssl certificates, per each request your client (apps) tries to perform. it is meant to prevent an attacker to perform a man in the middle attack using proxies, basically preventing the usage of self signed root certificate on a device and therefore preventing him to spoof the data going in and out the app. Data is still untouched and not additionally encrypted. During the request handshake step, you check if the received certificate is contained into your cert array, if not, you drop the request

Comment: Also, the symmetric/asymmetric encryption still requires at an initial point a key exchange (unless you hardcode the keys both client and server side, which is not recommended),  and if by chance an attacked intercept the key data exchange in that exact moment, your data being encrypted later on would not be secur anyhow as the attached previously got the keys to decrypt the data. That’s why you normally need to make the data transmission safe enough in first place, then you can always decide to build more layers on top of it if really needed

Comment: *...if by chance an attacker intercept the key data exchange in that exact moment ... would not be secure anyhow ... as the attacker previously got the keys ...* I'm not exactly sure what you're implying there but the only keys ever exposed during thr SSL/TLS handshake protocol are public keys. These don't allow an attacker to do anything.

Comment: I was referring the case of symmetrical encryption scenario such as AES-256 not an RSA but that’s not the point. As I said before, the channel must be structured and designed as safe as possible, and I mentioned protocol implementation like OAuth just not to reinvent the wheel. Done that, the developer can decide to encrypt the transferred data, back and forth, according with his own standard of performance e desired security

Comment: Thanks! It looks like Certificate Pinning will block Charles and such from being able to access the data going out